# How to update the second sub class Only when a value change in the parent class

Tags: flutter

I have pageview.builder widget i want when the index change the sub class change with the setstate to update the index. where the user can know in which image he is viewing now. but i don't want to update the whole class only for changing the number of the index, so i made another class for updating the index but in the onchangepage the second class doesn't update;
Parent Class:

```
 child: PageView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  onPageChanged: (currentIndex) {
                    // here when the value change i want to notify the second class
                  },
                  itemCount: images.length,
```

SubClass

```
class Number extends StatefulWidget {
final List<File> images;
final int index;

const Number({required this.images, required this.index, Key? key})
  : super(key: key);

@override
State<Number> createState() => _NumberState();
}

class _NumberState extends State<Number> {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print(widget.index);
return Container(
  height: 5.h,
  width: double.infinity,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Row(
    children: widget.images.map((_) {
      return Container(
        height: 3.h,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.h),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simple and you must use state management.

some famous state management packages: Provider, Riverpod, Getx, Bloc and ..

Comment: yes i used state management for that, and it works but i thought there is a way to do without state management ?

Comment: Yes, you can with some tricks, one of these tricks: you create an object from Number  class and define a method for setState into that. To understand this trick see (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Il9PBK-Vfc-lQSjCzDn32cqzZxbU9PDpC5Mhz1rL84s/edit?usp=sharing)